# Do downvotes lower reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Do downvotes lower reputation? I answered a question and it got down voted I had 5 reputation prior to that. After It happened I noticed I couldn’t post to the Meta which gave me the idea that downvotes lower reputation.

Comment: I encourage you to read our [help page on reputation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).  It explains all the ways to gain and lose rep.  Note that on the Meta site, you do not lose reputation nor gain any for any actions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Getting a question or answer downvoted (on the normal site, not on Meta) will lower your reputation score by 2 points. It costs 1 rep to downvote <strike>a post</strike> an answer. You can find more info on how reputation works in the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: It costs 1 rep to downvote *answers*. There's no rep penalty for downvoting questions.